# Question about a proof related to cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $a$ in a group and $i, k \in \mathbb N.$ Prove $H = (a^i) \cap (a^k)$ is a cyclic subgroup of $(a)$ and $H = (a^{lcm(i, k)}).$
>
> Proof: Since $(a)$ is cyclic and $H$ is a subgroup of $(a)$, $H$ is cyclic. Since $\frac {k}{gcd(i, k)} \in \mathbb Z,$ we have $(a^{lcm(i, k)}) = (a^i)^{\frac {k}{gcd(i, k)}}.$ Then $(a^{lcm(i, k)}) \subset (a^i).$ Also, $(a^{lcm(i, k)}) \subset (a^k).$ Hence $(a^{lcm(i, k)}) \subset H.$ Now let $h \in H.$ Then $h = a^j = (a^i)^n = (a^k)^m$ for some $j, m, n \in \mathbb Z.$ So $i, k \mid j$ and so $lcm(i, k) \mid j.$ Thus $h = a^j = (a^{lcm(i, k)})^c$ So, $h \in (a^{lcm(i, k)}).$

I don't quite understand how they got $(a^{lcm(i, k)}) \subset (a^i)$ and $h \in (a^{lcm(i, k)})$. Please, comment on these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because for any multiple $l$ of $k$, $(a^l)\subset (a^k)$ since $a^l\in (a^k)$, and $\operatorname{lcm}(i,k)$ is a multiple of both $i$ and $k$.

Comment: @ Bernard, when we write $a^{lcm(i, k)} = (a^i)^{\frac{k}{lcm(i, k)}}$, are we comparing an element to a set(group)?

Comment: This is written nowhere in the proof, and is meaningless.

Comment: @ Bernard, I actually messed up the proof when copying it here. Here's a [link](http://s9.postimg.org/ak0eulekv/group.png) to the full version from my book. The equality appears in the 3rd sentence from the top.

Comment: Sorry, it was not written in your post indeed, but it's meaningful. The parentheses here do not  denote the ideal generated by $a^i$, but are a separator for a power of a power. So you have only elements. I agree this may be  confusional.